# When is Swiping Intuitive?

Tags: gestures, swipe

What sort of operations make sense with swipe gestures? For dating apps, swiping left and right make sense because the context of the operation is sorting. Some go left, others go right. Goats and sheep etc.

Our app is a game, and it's possible to send messages to other users. There would be a send message screen. If the background of the screen has a mailbox on the right, and a garbage bin on the left, then swiping left and right can be used as the user input for "send the message" and "cancel message" respectively. However, does that make sense?

Comment: Things are intuitive when they are familiar with things you've used in the past. There's no need to invent a new method of sending and canceling a message, just see what other popular messaging and mailing apps do and take your lead from that.

Comment: Okay, I'll talk to product dev. I'm not the UX designer (I'm the Javascript dev) and it feels kind of gimmicky to me. They're hoping to get into some sort of swipe bandwagon or something.

Comment: In languages that are written left to right, it probably (sort of) makes sense; but in languages that are written right to left, it might not make sense. However, as Fractional said, if other messaging apps don't do it, then users won't be familiar with it. And I agree with you, Jon, that it feels gimmicky.

Comment: @JonAbaca I might try to write up a fuller answer for you later, but here's a write up on what makes something intuitive https://blog.prototypr.io/the-secret-to-designing-intuitive-products-d5be54228526

Answer (score 1):

While an interaction like that might not be intuitive at first, you could still teach the user by having the usual send and cancel buttons, but showing a short animation of the message going into the mailbox/trashcan. For a real example, Tinder shows an animation of the card getting swiped when the ❌ or ❤ button is pressed. Usually, the user realizes they can also swipe the cards after seeing that.

Comment: Oh, I don't have the tinder app so I didn't realize that they have buttons. Would you say the buttons are necessary because some users don't have the dexterity to perform a swipe?